# Is it possible to bypass this csp?

Tags: web-application, xss, content-security-policy

Today I created a web application. I'm using this csp to avoid xss attacks. CSP: `` Content-Security-Policy", `child-src 'none'; connect-src 'none'; default-src 'none'; font-src 'none'; frame-src 'none'; img-src 'none'; manifest-src 'none'; media-src 'none'; object-src 'none'; prefetch-src 'none'; script-src 'report-sample'; style-src 'report-sample'; worker-src 'none'; `` Does anyone know if its still possible to xss? If so, how? My web app is an extremely simple pastebin website.

Comment: `script-src 'report-sample'` isn't that essentially not restricting script at all, but only report violations (there are non though since there are no restrictions). Also, why do you explicitly set all the policies explicitly to `'none`'  given that you already have a `default-src 'none'`?

Comment: I have no idea, the more the better i guess

Comment: Essentially, your CSP disallows everything.

Comment: A good resource is https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/

Comment: Still an experiment, but a successful one: [trusted types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/trusted-types).

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you mean by bypassing CSP. XSS (injecting user controlled HTML code) is possible in case of rendering unescaping user input, but it is impossible to exploit XSS, since you have completely prohibited styles and scripts.

But Clickjacking is possible since an absence of `frame-ancestors` directive.
Form redirection is also possible, since there is no `form-action` directive.

Pls note that `script-src 'report-sample';` [completely forbids](https://csplite.com/csp/test180/) any script on page, and `style-src 'report-sample';` forbids any CSS style.
Thus, it will be a site with default styles built into the browser and no interactive interaction with visitors.